# Don't agree with first-posts review audit

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

[Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2989914) to the audit I've failed today.

Briefly, the principal content of the question:

> Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodException ... while trying to run a word count application on Amazon Elastic MapReduce

and the answer (to be reviewed, expected to downvote/flag/edit):

> please check that you using correct library /jar file while compiling and running the program

I disagree that the audit is correct. A wrong JAR could very well be the reason for the `NoSuchMethodException` mentioned in the question.

Yes, the post is very short and definitely not of best quality, but it does attempt to answer the question, and the question in its current state probably can't be answered any better. 
Besides, the answer has only one downvote, and there are tons of such one-sentence answers out there. Should they all be flagged?

If such posts are included in audits, then it really becomes necessary to open the question and see if an answer still exists, although I don't like doing this.

Comment: Hopefully, I would have skipped this audit.

Comment: I usually skip when I'm not sure. There's always someone else who may know better.

Comment: @Szymon: I'd skip this audit if I didn't know of JARs, `NoSuchMethodException`s, etc, but I see no reason to skip it otherwise. Of course, I'm *not* the best Java expert in the world. There's always folks who are better on *any* issue than yourself, but we don't want John Skeet to do all the audits.

Answer (score 9):

I probably would have skipped this one as well, but my guess is that "Please check [xyz]" is generally a debugging step that helps you arrive at the answer, but not the answer itself, hence why it should be a comment..